# C# using an enumerator to change values of the underlying data

Tags: c#, accord.net

Using Accord.net KD Tree library. I have the following code:

```
        Accord.Collections.KDTree<Coordinate> tree = new Accord.Collections.KDTree<Coordinate>(3);
        Coordinate point = new Coordinate(5, 5, 5);
        double[] temp = { 5, 5, 5 };
        tree.Add(temp, point);
        temp = new double[] { 1,1,1 };
        tree.Add(temp, point);
        temp = new double[] { 6,6,6 };
        tree.Add(temp, point);

        var en = tree.GetEnumerator();
        while (en.MoveNext())
        {
            en.Current.Value.PointStatus = 99;
        }
    }
```

There are three values in the tree - indexes 0,1,2. When the while loop runs at the bottom of the code in the first iteration I am expecting only the value for the current (first) entity to be changes to 99. Instead all three entities change to 99.

New to C# and still learning. What could be happening here.

[Here is a link](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/M_Accord_Collections_BinaryTree_1_GetEnumerator.htm) to the docs on GetEnumerator.

EDIT:
When I use the same instance of temp and then add a breakpoint the vaules are displayed as being unique:
[image]

If I then get the enumerator and use the following code:

```
Coordinate[] coords = new Coordinate[] { };
var en = tree.GetEnumerator();
while (en.MoveNext())
{
    Console.WriteLine(en.Current.Value.X);
}
```

I get:

> 5
>
> 5
>
> 5

It looks to me that I am in fact storing a reference to the data and the data is a single object. THe puzzle now is what does the compiler show the wrong valus at breakpoint?

Comment: Why are you only expecting the first entity to be changed? You're calling `MoveNext` in a loop which you never leave (until MoveNext returns false when it reaches the end of the list).

Comment: Change the `while` to an `if`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the `PointStatus` is a property from `Coordinate point` class. Class is a reference type.

You are adding `Coordinate point`, **which is created once**, 3 times for 3 different temp values. Point reference remains same.

**If you change at one place it will reflect everywhere because you are doing changes directly in the object**. It is not like a copy in value types.

Result you are getting is expected.

**Edit:**

Debugger is showing values of temp which is a double array. That is just the set of few values of the properties in every object inside a tree list.

If you will expand each item 0, 1 and 2, you will see the complete information.

`Current.Value.X` would be returning the value of one of the properties of Coordinate class object which is created once.

Comment: you are indeed correct. Please see the edit to my original question above.